# How to solve the LCM in 50 bytes of Python

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, tips, python

I've recently stumbled upon a Russian site called [acmp.ru](https://acmp.ru/), in which one of the tasks, [HOK](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=14), asks us to find the LCM of two positive integers. The full statement, translated to English is as follows:

> The only line of the input contains two natural numbers A and B separated by a space, not exceeding 46340. 
> In the only line of the output, you need to output one integer - the LCM of the numbers A and B.

On the [Python leaderboard](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=bstatus&id_t=14&lang=PY), the top solution is just 50 bytes, followed by a stream of 52s.

[image]

Note that the scoring method for this site is *not* standard, and uses the following formula:

> max(code length without spaces, tabs and newlines, full code length divided by 4)

With this in mind, I have come up with two solutions that give a score of 52. One of them simply uses `math.lcm`, while the other one calculates it more directly:

```py
from math import*
print(lcm(*map(int,input().split())))
```

```py
a,b=map(int,input().split())
v=a
while v%b:v+=a
print(v)
```

Now I'm stumped. How can I save 2 bytes off my solution? (the Python version is 3.9.5).

Comment: could it be with python 2 ?

Comment: Is it counted in bytes or characters?

Comment: @MarcMush The judge runs on Python 3.9.5, so that is the only version I can submit to.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino As far as I've tested, it is counted in bytes. Submitting multi-byte characters seems to inflate the score.

Comment: But the top solution was written in July 2016, right? There was only Python 2 and Python 3 at that time. (Python 3.6 was apparently released in December.)

Comment: Execution time and memory usage might be another clue of the approach taken.

Comment: Also, for numbers not exceeding 46340, the worst case is (46337, 46327) which results in the answer of 2146654199.

Comment: The 7.2 megabytes of memory used makes me think there's arithmetic generating-function-style tricks in play. Like, for `gcd`, there's `gcd(a,b)==B**(a*b)//~-B**a%~-B**b%B` some a large enough value `B`.

Comment: Actually, the 52's are also using on the order of a megabyte of memory, so I don't know what's going on there. Are there a huge number of test cases? Or is this just par for the tester?

Comment: Does it work to replace `print` with `input` and terminate with error? If so, aliasing `I=input` saves a byte because the newline doesn't count.

Comment: @xnor I've explored that before, but unfortunately it requires a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Is is possible the solution is shelling out to the system?

Comment: I assume non standard modules are not allowed, but if they were `from numpy import *` `print(math.lcm(*mat(input()).A1))` for 49 by their counting method. Using the facts that numpy imports math and the obscure matrix class has a rather friendly constructor and a factory function with a short name.

Comment: Actually, there is an 'lcm' in the numpy namespace, so that would be 44 https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chrzS3oFIhM7cgv6hEi6ugKDOvRCMnOVdDKzexRCMzr6C0RENTU8/RUFPz/38TM2NjcwUgaWQOAA

Comment: @Sisyphus It's such a simple task, yet seemingly impossible to golf further. I wouldn't be surprised if it were, although I'd have no idea how to approach it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

***My solution to 50 bytes:***

```py
v=1
for x in input().split()*6**6:v+=-v%int(x)
print(v)
```

#### Explanation

The solution itself is relatively simple, but finding it was significantly more difficult.

First, note that the LCM of `a` and `b` is the smallest number `v` such that `v%a==0` and `v%b==0`.

The main logic for this algorithm is in `v+=-v%int(x)`. In a nutshell, it sets `v` to the first multiple of `x` greater than or equal to `v`. This means that if `v%x==0`, `v` doesn't change.

In a `for` loop, we repeat this process cyclically with both numbers. Whenever `v` is not divisible by `x`, `v+=-v%x` ensures that `v` becomes the immediate next divisor of `x`. This means that, at some point in the loop, `v` will equal the LCM. When it does, `v` will stop changing, since both numbers will be divisible by `v`.

To better illustrate the algorithm, here is an example on the input `36 27`:

```py
                v=1
(36): v+=-v%36; v=36
(27): v+=-v%27; v=54
(36): v+=-v%36; v=72
(27): v+=-v%27; v=81
(36): v+=-v%36; v=108
(27): v+=-v%27; v=108
(36): v+=-v%36; v=108
...
```

It remains to determine how many iterations are required. In the worst case, `A` and `B` are coprime, for which the LCM is `A*B`. For this, we would need exactly `min(A,B)` iterations. The statement tells us that both numbers are guaranteed to be at most `46340`. We could simply use this number, but `6**6` is one shorter, and only does `316` extra operations.